# Why can "core" be a plural form of "core"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, plural-forms, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

According to [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/core.html):

> The noun **core** can be countable or uncountable.
>
> In more general, commonly used, contexts, the plural form will also be
>   **core**.
>
> However, in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be **cores**
>   e.g. in reference to various types of cores or a collection of **cores**.

But doesn't it seem that in the general case the word actually is uncountable? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/core) or [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/core) dictionaries don't say anything about its plural form.

Another point: Google Ngram shows that "to their core" is used more than "to their cores" [38 times](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+their+core%2C+to+their+cores&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20their%20core%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20their%20cores%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20their%20core%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20their%20cores%3B%2Cc1). Does this mean that "core" in this case is not specific? But the word "their" indicates that the context is specific.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because the question relies on the spurious authority of WordHippo when there are many far more reliable sources of information available on the internet. Merriam Webster. Cambridge. Oxford. Longmans. Collins. etc

Comment: This discussion has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77399/discussion-on-question-by-ooker-why-can-core-be-a-plural-form-of-core).  If you'd like to continue the discussion, please use the chat room or see the related meta question: [Why should question contain incorrect source be downvoted?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4701/11458)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literally, the word [*core*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/core) refers to things inside a 3D structure (fruit, planets, etc). Figuratively, *core* has the notion of the thing or value etc that is 'central' or 'most important'. When used in the figurative sense (and in relation to a plurality of individuals, not just one individual), the term is conventionally used when there is one value or principle or 'heart' etc that is common to the whole group. In a sense, it wouldn't be 'core' if there were more than one of those things.

If *core* is used as a modifier (e.g. *core activities* - see below), then the word *core* is properly used in its base form, regardless of the number of (say) activities are involved.

> **core** *noun*
>   The part of something that is central to its existence or character.
>   ‘the plan has the interests of children at its core’
>   (as modifier) ‘managers can concentrate on their core activities’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/core)

I'm not familiar with how WordHippo is set up. In particular, I don't know whether this is crowd-sourced information at one extreme or whether it is curated by a panel of experts at the other. The entry you link to has no examples of what it means by "the plural form will also be core", so I can't tell you what they were referring to. At a guess, they might have been referring to the 'modifier' sense in the dictionary example above.

The Ngram link you provided (and clicking through to ["to their core"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20their%20core%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)) does have examples, though, so I'll comment on a few here:

> Many people had found their refuge here; many people had connected to their heart and to their core here.
>   [- Four Sides to the Core](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=N_hfAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&dq=%22to%20their%20core%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR8pHz6fjaAhULWrwKHY8FAw8Q6AEIKTAA)

The terms *heart* and *core* are used in the uncountable sense of 'basic value'. You can compare this with, say, "found their *love*" (uncountable) and contrast it with, say, "found their *hobbies*" (countable).

> I started a journey toward stripping the standards to get to their core.
>   [- The Core Deconstructed](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=6WG6BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&dq=%22to%20their%20core%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR8pHz6fjaAhULWrwKHY8FAw8Q6AEILzAB)

This uses the term *core* in the 'collective *most important* bit' sense, hence the use of the singular. It can alternatively be read as a figurative use, which justifies using the base case.

> Following this line of thinking, Chauncey Billups and Chris Bosh are both exceptional NBA basketball players, but they have unique, individualized needs relating to their core functionality.
>   [- Conditioning to the Core](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=ZabiAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA359&dq=%22to%20their%20core%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR8pHz6fjaAhULWrwKHY8FAw8Q6AEIOzAD)

This uses the term *core* in the *modifier* sense (one noun modifying another), which justifies using the base case.

Note that the term *core* is not used in a plural sense in any of the above examples.

The ["to their cores"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20their%20cores%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) click-through from your Ngram link does show some examples of *cores* used in the plural sense. Glancing at a few examples, it seems that in each case they refer to different 'cores' (e.g. one 'main thing' per company, not a unifying 'main thing' for the collection of companies), whether literal or figurative. The chart from your Ngram link shows that this usage appears less often than the singular or base case "to their core" (at least, in Ngram's database).

In any case, contrary to WordHippo's assertion, the examples above support the notion that **the term *core* isn't used in the 'singular' to indicate the plural**.

Comment: Good answer, especially the comparison with other abstract concepts like *love*.  There are many nouns that fall into this category and have similar behavior.